# Vue warns property not set, even though it is set

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a form with inputs bound to my vue instance with v-model. There is a textbox and several checkboxes. All bound properties are initialized in the data section in my JS. Despite this, vue warns that the properties are "not defined on the instance but referenced during render." Despite this, the page renders properly with the correct initialized values. Furthermore, these warnings only pop for the checkboxes and not the text input.

I'm at a total loss as to why or even if this is a problem (everything works; it's only the mass amount of warnings that appear in the console that gives me pause)

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Scan:</h2>
  <form id="formNewScan"  @submit="onNewScanSubmit">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-form-label" for="scanName">Scan Name:</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control col-md-10" id="scanName" type="text" placeholder="MyScan" v-model="userData.scanName"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="my-3"/>
    <div class="form-group row">

      <input id="scanOS" type="checkbox" v-model="userData.scanOS"/>
      <label class="col-form-label" v-bind:for="scanOS" >OS Scan</label>
      <input id="scanFF" type="checkbox" v-model="userData.scanFF"/>
      <label class="col-form-label" v-bind:for="scanFF" >Firefox Scan</label>
      <input id="scanHTTPD" type="checkbox" v-model="userData.scanHTTPD"/>
      <label class="col-form-label" v-bind:for="scanHTTPD" >Apache httpd Scan</label>
      <input id="scanTC" type="checkbox" v-model="userData.scanTC"/>
      <label class="col-form-label" v-bind:for="scanTC" >Apache Tomcat Scan</label>
      <input id="scanManual" type="checkbox" v-model="userData.scanManual"/>
      <label class="col-form-label" v-bind:for="scanManual" >Grab System Info</label>
      <input id="scanSCC" type="checkbox" v-model="userData.scanSCC"/>
      <label class="col-form-label" v-bind:for="scanSCC" >SCC</label>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    userData: {
      scanName: "",
      scanOS: true,
      scanFF: true,
      scanHTTPD: false,
      scanTC: false,
      scanManual: false,
      scanSCC: false,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onNewScanSubmit: function() {
        console.log("Hello")
    }
  }
})
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/La2uv3tn/

EDIT: I had copied and pasted my inputs and didn't change the `v-bind:for` back to just `for`. I am now also realizing the console warning specifically said "scanOS" as opposed to "userData.scanOS". I guess that's what I get for naming the variables the same as the element IDs....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding strings as variables. Try replacing all occurrences of `v-bind:for="` with `for="` in label tags. Since for ex, scanOS in `v-bind:for="scanOS"` is a string, Vuejs cannot find the variable `scanOS`.